# Is it possible to find $\lim_{x\to\infty}\cos\left(\frac2x\right)^{x^2}$ without variable substitution?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I was wondering if it was possible to find  $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\cos\left(\frac2x\right)^{x^2}$$
without variable substitution? If so, how? Here is the work I've tried, we are specifically told to use L'Hospital's Rule:

lim x-> infinity (ln(cos(2/x))/(1/x^2) - This will get it to the form 0/0 and allow me to use L'Hospital's Rule

lim x-> infinity (2sin(2x)/ x^2 cos(2/x)) / ((-2/x^3))

By simplifying this down, I got

lim x-> infinity (-x sin(2/x)) / cos(2/x)

Plugging in infinity, I got this

(-infinity)(sin(0) / cos(0) = 0/1 = 0

e^0 = 1, which is not the correct answer of 1/e^2

I'm confused on where I'm going wrong. My professor's answer key says to substitute u = x/2, but that has confused me more, which is why I'm trying to figure out how to do the limit without it. Thank you for your input!

(Forgive my formatting, I'm new to the site and unsure of how to input my work)

Comment: The standard first technique when trying to apply L'Hopital to functions of the form $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is to take the log and rewrite as a fraction, such as (but not limited to)

$$\frac{\ln(f(x))}{1/g(x)}$$

If you want more help, [edit] your post to include what you've tried; we're generally not a site where it's kosher to just post a question as if we're supposed to do as the legwork (intentional or otherwise).

Comment: Why use L’Hospital in this example? A Taylor approximation of $\ln\circ f$ is simpler here. Oh but I see @Blue just changed your title. Do you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \cos\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^{x^2}&=
\exp \left(\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \ln\left(\cos\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^{x^2}\right)\right)\\
&=
\exp \left(\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} x^2\ln\cos\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)\right)\\
&\overset{L.H.}=\exp \left(\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\ln\cos\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)\\
&=\exp \left(\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\left(-\tan\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)\right)(-\frac{2}{x^2})}{-\frac{2}{x^3}}\right)\\
&\overset{L.H.}=\exp \left(\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{-\tan\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}} \right)\\
&=\exp \left(\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{-\sec^2\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)(-\frac{2}{x^2})}{-\frac{1}{x^2}} \right)\\
&=\exp \left(\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} -2\sec^2\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)\right)\\
&=\exp(-2)\\
&=e^{-2}\\
\end{align}$

$L.H.$: L'Hospital rule.

Comment: Just curious, why would not changing sin/cos into tangent throw off the entire problem, like in my work above? Is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: Your formatting is not readible.

Comment: You don't have to use tan, cot, sec, csc functions anywhere. Sin and cos are enough.

Answer (score 1):

As $x\to\infty,$ $$x^2\ln\left(\cos\frac2x\right)=x^2\ln\left(1-\frac2{x^2}+o(1/x^2)\right)\sim
x^2\left(-\frac2{x^2}\right)$$ hence
$$\left(\cos\left(\frac2x\right)\right)^{x^2}\to e^{-2}.$$

Note that one could also interpret your $\cos\left(\frac2x\right)^{x^2}$ as $\cos\left(\left(\frac2x\right)^{x^2}\right),$ whose limit as $x\to+\infty$ is $1.$

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
\cos\left(\frac2x\right)^{x^2}
&\approx\left(1-\frac{(\frac2x)^2}{2}\right)^{x^2}\\
&=\left(1-\frac{2}{x^2}\right)^{x^2}\\
&=\left(\left(1-\frac{2}{x^2}\right)^{\frac{x^2}{2}}\right)^2\\
&\to e^{-2}
\qquad\text{(since } (1-\frac1{x})^x \to e^{-1}
\text{ as } x \to \infty)\\
\end{array}
$